# What happens when overloading ->* operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was going through this particular example of overloading ->*  operator. I tried hard to get over why do we need to overload () operator but couldn't get it after a lot of googling and reerences.Eckel says that When operator ->* is called, the compiler immediately turns around and calls operator() for the return value of operator ->* . Now I know that what we want with this ->* operator is to act like a smart pointer for a class that is it should be able to reference the member functions just like a normal pointer does . So we do it like (w->* pmf)(1) and here I think that the ->* needs to know about the return value of the int in () that's why it is being overloaded on top of ->* operator. Another doubt I had in case of nested iterators that why do we need to declare the nested class before declaring it as a friend while doing overloading of -> to make it like nested iterator? I am a beginner in C++ that's why these questions may seem too naive to some sorry for that but yeah I would like a very in-depth knowledge of this stuff because I have been struggling a lot with overloading -> and ->* till now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dog {
    public:
    int run(int i) const {
        cout << "run\n";
        return i;
    }
    int eat(int i) const {
        cout << "eat\n";
        return i;
    }
    int sleep(int i) const {
        cout << "ZZZ\n";
        return i;
    }
    typedef int (Dog::*PMF)(int) const;
    // operator->* must return an object
    // that has an operator():
    class FunctionObject {
        Dog* ptr;
        PMF pmem;
        public:
        // Save the object pointer and member pointer
        FunctionObject(Dog* wp, PMF pmf): ptr(wp), pmem(pmf) {
            cout << "FunctionObject constructor\n";
        }
        // Make the call using the object pointer
        // and member pointer
        int operator()(int i) const {
            cout << "FunctionObject::operator()\n";
            return (ptr->*pmem)(i); // Make the call
        }
    };
    FunctionObject operator->*(PMF pmf) {
        cout << "operator->*" << endl;
        return FunctionObject(this, pmf);
    }
};
int main() {
    Dog w;
    Dog::PMF pmf = &Dog::run;
    cout << (w->*pmf)(1) << endl;
    pmf = &Dog::sleep;
    cout << (w->*pmf)(2) << endl;
    pmf = &Dog::eat;
    cout << (w->*pmf)(3) << endl;
}
```

Comment: @aleguna:There is such an operator . I am citing this from Bruce Eckel. He won't tell it wrong

Comment: @aleguna it's called the pointer-to-member operator.

Comment: @aleguna: `->*` is one of the pointer-to-member access operators, the other being `.*`.

Comment: @PaulR: I want to know the insides of overloading ->* operator . The above answer doesn't answer that . It tells about smart pointers and that I know how they are used .

Comment: @PaulR: Here there is no discussion about overloading () for overloading ->*

Comment: @KavishDwivedi: there isn't much discussion to be had. Your expression looks like `(w->*pmf)(1)`. So `operator()` is called on the result of `(w->*pmf)`. If your expression had looked like `(w->*pmf) + 1` then `operator+` would be called on the result of `(w->*pmf)`.